# Adding Combobox to Python Toolbox tool dialog?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, combo-box

I am trying to create a Python Toolbox tool which is supposed to add two fields `State` and `StateAbb` to selected Shapefile from selected combobox.

How I can add a Combobox which contains a list of US states to the Tool?

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "states"
        self.alias = "states"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [states]


class states(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "states Tool"
        self.description = "Add and Insert Value from Combo"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="1- State Street Layer",
            name="in_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        params = [param0]

        return params


    def execute(self, params, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        arcpy.AddField_management(params[0],"area","TEXT","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(params[0],"area","!shape.area@squaremeters!","PYTHON_10.3","#")


        return
```

Comment: can you explain what a combo-box is?

Comment: You are using a Python Toolbox tool not a Python Script tool.

Comment: @Geo.Dude https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ["Value List"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)

```
param.filter.type = "ValueList"
param.filter.list = [a, list, of, states]
```

E.g.

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "states"
        self.alias = "states"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [States]



class States(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "states Tool"
        self.description = "Add and Insert Value from Combo"
        self.canRunInBackground = False
        self.states = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ', 'Arkansas': 'AR', 
                       'California': 'CA', 'Colorado': 'CO', 'Connecticut': 'CT', 
                       'Delaware': 'DE', 'Florida': 'FL', 'Georgia': 'GA', 'Hawaii': 'HI', 
                       'Idaho': 'ID', 'Illinois': 'IL', 'Indiana': 'IN', 'Iowa': 'IA', 
                       'Kansas': 'KS', 'Kentucky': 'KY', 'Louisiana': 'LA', 'Maine': 'ME', 
                       'Maryland': 'MD', 'Massachusetts': 'MA', 'Michigan': 'MI', 
                       'Minnesota': 'MN', 'Mississippi': 'MS', 'Missouri': 'MO', 
                       'Montana': 'MT', 'Nebraska': 'NE', 'Nevada': 'NV', 'New Hampshire': 'NH', 
                       'New Jersey': 'NJ', 'New Mexico': 'NM', 'New York': 'NY', 
                       'North Carolina': 'NC', 'North Dakota': 'ND', 'Ohio': 'OH', 'Oklahoma': 'OK', 
                       'Oregon': 'OR', 'Pennsylvania': 'PA', 'Rhode Island': 'RI', 
                       'South Carolina': 'SC', 'South Dakota': 'SD', 'Tennessee': 'TN', 
                       'Texas': 'TX', 'Utah': 'UT', 'Vermont': 'VT', 'Virginia': 'VA', 
                       'Washington': 'WA', 'West Virginia': 'WV', 'Wisconsin': 'WI', 
                       'Wyoming': 'WY', 'American Samoa': 'AS', 'District of Columbia': 'DC', 
                       'Guam': 'GU', 'Northern Mariana Islands': 'MP', 'Puerto Rico': 'PR', 
                       'United States Virgin Islands': 'VI'}

    def getParameterInfo(self):

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="1- State Street Layer",
            name="in_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="State",
            name="state",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Set a value list of States (and other US areas)
        param1.filter.type = "ValueList"
        param1.filter.list = sorted(self.states.keys())


        params = [param0, param1]

        return params


    def execute(self, params, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        state = params[1].valueAsText
        abbr = self.states[state]

        #Do something with state and abbr

        return
```